# Regular expression to enforce 2 digits after decimal point

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate a numeric string with JavaScript, to ensure the number has exactly two decimal places.

The validation will pass only if

1. the number has precisely two decimal places
2. there is at least one digit before the decimal point. (could be zero)
3. the number before the decimal point can not begin with more than one zero.

Valid numbers:

```
0.01
0.12
111.23
1234.56
012345.67
123.00
0.00
```

Invalid numbers:

```
.12
1.1
0.0
00.00
1234.
1234.567
1234
00123.45
abcd.12
12a4.56
1234.5A
```

I have tried the regular expression `[0-9][\.][0-9][0-9]$`, but it allows letters before decimal point like `12a4.56`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.` matches any character, it does not do what you think it does. You have to escape it. Also, you have two more errors; try

```
^[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]$
```

instead, or even better, use `\d` for decimal digits:

```
^\d+\.\d\d$
```

Comment: Hi H2C03, your expression is accepting .12, .34 etc which should not be passed.

Comment: @ManasSaha Ah, so you want at least one number before the decimal point. Here you are.

Comment: A character class including a dot matches a literal dot, not any character. The real problem is, that the OP did not force digits to immediately follow after the beginning, i.e. no `^`, also he does not allow for multiple digits before the decimal point. `[.]` was perfectly fine.

Comment: @phant0m You're righm however I just guessed about where the dot was used, as OP hasn't provided the code he had tried. Also, my regex solves both of the problems you listed (and that I also noticed). But feel free to vote down if you think this is a bad answer.

Comment: He provided the regex: `[0-9][.][0-9][0-9]$` ;) Also, you could use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a bad answer, I was just assuming that you did see that regex the OP provided. Comments are here to point out mistakes (among other things of course), and that's what I wanted to do.

Comment: @phant0m That's perfectly right, however, there's no regex in the current question and there's no available edit history, so essentially I cannot possibly know what it contained before the edit.

Comment: In the current question, there is the regex I provided above, it's just below the code section, but not within backticks and thus not very noticeable ;)

Comment: Heh, he even had a backslash before the dot inside the character class (which is not necessary of course), but markdown swallowed it.

Comment: What will be the regex if I added 1234 in Valid numbers (means a user can enter an integer number or only 2 digits after decimal i.e 1234 or 1234.12)?

Answer (score 7):

[This covers all requirements](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%280%7C%280?%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%2a%29%29%5C.%5Cd%5Cd%24&input=0.01%0A0.12%0A111.23%0A1234.56%0A012345.67%0A123.00%0A0.00%0A%0A.12%0A1.1%0A0.0%0A00.00%0A1234.%0A1234.567%0A1234%0A00123.45%0Aabcd.12%0A12a4.56%0A1234.5A):

```
^(0|0?[1-9]\d*)\.\d\d$
```

- the number has precisely two decimal places

  - Trivially satisfied due to the non-optional `\.\d\d$`

The other two conditions can be restated as follows:

- The number before the decimal points is either a zero
- or a number with exactly one zero, then a number that does *not* start with zero

This is covered in these two cases:

- `0`
- `0?[1-9]\d*`

Comment: Greetings! What is the purpose of the second zero? Is it for octal? What if `(0|[1-9][0-9]*)` instead of `(0|0?[1-9][0-9]*)`?

Comment: @Artfaith it's just what the OP requested for some reason in their "valid numbers" example, `012345.67`

Answer (score 4):

You don't need regular expressions for this.

JavaScript has a function [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) that will do what you need.

```
var fixedtotwodecimals = floatvalue.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: I believe OP wants to validate user input (i. e. a boolean), and not correct/fix it if it's invalid.

Comment: yes... so compare original value with toFixed value. you still don't need regex.

Answer (score 2):

i used this

> ^[1-9][1-9]*[.]?[1-9]{0,2}$

- 0 not accept
- 123.12 accept but 123.123 not accept
- 1 accept
- 12213123 accept
- sdfsf not accept
- 15.12 accept
- 15@12 not accept
- 15&12 not accept

Comment: This not accept 320 or 1.10, you can change for ^[1-9][0-9]*[.]?[0-9]{0,2}$

Answer (score 1):

```
var values='0.12';

document.write(values.match(/\d+[.]+\d+\d/));
```

change value as you want and check it

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
^(0[.]+\d{2})|^[1-9]\d+[.]+\d{2}$
```

Comment: This is wrong, it matches `0.110.11` for instance. You are missing parentheses, the `^` after the `|` is wrong `[.]+` should not have a `+`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
pattern="[0-9]*(\.?[0-9]{1,2}$)?"
```

- 1 Valid
- 1.1 Valid
- 1.12 Valid
- 1.123 not Valid
- only number Valid

  pattern="[0-9]*(.?[0-9]{2}$)?"
- 1 Valid
- 1.1 not Valid
- 1.12 Valid
- 1.123 not Valid
- only number Valid