# Javascript Regex for decimal

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex for a 5 digit integer number with 2 decimals.

These would be correct:

- 12345.12
- 09856.99
- 45123.00

These wouldn't:

- 123.12
- 12345.6
- 98652

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What have you tried?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208364/regular-expression-to-enforce-2-digits-after-decimal-point

Comment: What if it has 6 digits and decimals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex it will work

```
var regex = /^\d{5}\.\d{2}$/;
var num = '23445.09';
console.log(regex.test(num));  // True

var num2 = '12345.6'
console.log(regex.test(num));  // False
```

Demo : https://jsbin.com/wasefa/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: There's no need for the `?` either? It has to have 2 digits after decimal point.

Comment: I would change the line to `var regex = /^\d{5}\.\d{2}$/;`

Comment: Thanks for suggestions dudes !!

Comment: This worked, thank you very much!

Comment: Most welcome and thanks @pwagner for your suggestion !!

Answer (score 0):

This would be correct : `/^\d{5}\.\d{2}$/`

```
var value = 12345.12;
value.toString().match(/^\d{5}\.\d{2}$/); // ['12345.12']

var value = 98652;
value.toString().match(/^\d{5}\.\d{2}$/); // null
```

Comment: Same as the other answer, you need to escape your dot. Try it with `value = 12345678`

Comment: Thanks for that, you right. I edited my answer ;)