# How to use regular expression to keep four digit decimal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a input code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
  <title></title> 
  <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</script>
 </head> 
 <body> 
<input type="text" maxlength="11" class="text-right number inputMust" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/\d{11}+|^\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}?$/g,'')"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want the input allow most 11 digit integer and most 4 digit decimal?

If the input is not integer or decimal,replace the other characters.

And if the input is "0000000"，such a string of 0,keep only one 0.

These formats are allowed：

```
123456.1234 
1.23
12.3456
12.3456
1234567890
123456
12
0
```

These formats are not allowed：

```
123456.12345 
12345.1234564
12.3456789
12345678901234
1234567890.12
12.12345
123.123456
```

How to fix this `onkeyup="value=value.replace(/\d{11}+|^\d{1,4}\.\d{1,4}?$/g,'')"`

Comment: What is wrong with `1234567890.12`?

Comment: Maxlength is 11,`1234567890.12` is 13 digit.

Comment: What should the output be for something like `abc123` or `a4b23c`?

Comment: You include the `.` in the length of the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know how to do it now:

```
 $(".fourDigit").keyup(function(e) {
        var ele = e.target;
        val = ele.value;
        ret = val.replace(/[^\d\.]/g, '');
        ret = /[^\.]{0,}(\.\d{0,4})?/g.exec(ret);
        if(ret){
           ret = ret[0];
        }
        ret = ret.replace(/^0+/g, '0');
        ret = ret.replace(/^\.+/, '');
        ret = ret.substring(0, 11);
        ele.value = ret;
        });
```

Comment: if there is a comma you should use `.substring(0, 12)` because you have on extra (as you said max 11 digits)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken you can use javascript function called **toFixed()**

```
var fixedToFourDecimals = floatValue.toFixed(4);
```

And if you want to validate the user input you can compare toFixed() value with the original answer.

But if you still want to use Regex then go through [Regular expression to enforce 2 digits after decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208364/regular-expression-to-enforce-2-digits-after-decimal-point)
It uses 2 decimal not four but will provide you a good reference.

Answer (score 0):

Also a check if float and using local decimal separator.

```js
function localDecimalSeparator() {
    var n = 1.1;
    n = n.toLocaleString().substring(1, 2);
    return n;
}

function limitInput(element) {
  let value = parseFloat(element.value);
  if (!value) element.value = '';
  else {
    const decimal = localDecimalSeparator();
    let str = value.toString();
    let strSpl = str.split(decimal);
    if (strSpl.length > 1 && strSpl[1].length > 4) strSpl[1] = strSpl[1].substring(0, 4);
    if (element.value.indexOf(decimal) > -1) {
      strSpl[0] = strSpl[0] + decimal;
      str = strSpl.join('');
    }
    if (str.length > 10 + strSpl.length) str = str.substring(0, 10 + strSpl.length);
    element.value = str;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="limitInput(this);" />
```