# Need to get only two digits after decimal

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string with below format

```
const number = "21708.333333333336"
```

Then I pass it to the function to get the number in this format

```
"21,708.333333333336"
```

Function I am using for to do this (I have tried this)

```
let numberFormat = (x) => {
  return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')
}
```

But I need only last 2 digits

```
"21,708.33"
```

What should be the regex for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to enforce 2 digits after decimal point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208364/regular-expression-to-enforce-2-digits-after-decimal-point)

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/stkU1x/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```js
let result = Number("21708.333333333336").toLocaleString(undefined, {
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: HI can I format it this `1098958959` to this `(109) 895-8959`? using above

Comment: @Profer What you are asking is something not relevant to this question. You can ask another question regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

Before passing it to function which convert it to string use

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}

let number = "21708234234324.333333333336"

number = Number(number).toFixed(2);

numberWithCommas(number);
```

Comment: Converted it into number. Run above code in console.

Comment: Pls check the format as well what I want `"21,708.33"`. I am getting NAN

Comment: Thank you But User863's  answer is something extraordinary

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with basic funtionality

```
const number = "21708.333333333336"
function splitValue(value, index) {
    return parseInt(value.substring(0, index)) + "," + calc(value.substring(index));
}
function calc(theform) {
    var with2Decimals = theform.toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/)[0]
    return parseInt(with2Decimals);
}
var val = splitValue(number, 2);
console.log(val)
```